# Why Dictionary Add method throws exception when key is already present but HashSet does not

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary, hashset

I am trying to understand thought process behind this design decision. Also return type of Dictionary.Add is void. It would be nice to have same behavior for both data structures. Or is there any use case which makes current implementation a better choice?

> The HashSet class is based on the model of mathematical sets and provides high-performance set operations similar to accessing the keys of the Dictionary<TKey,TValue> or Hashtable collections. In simple terms, the HashSet class can be thought of as a Dictionary<TKey,TValue> collection without values.

Comment: *"The HashSet class can be thought of as a Dictionary<TKey,TValue> collection **without values**"* <-- this quote kind of answers your question for you:  without an attached value, there is no harm in replacing an existing item. With an attached value, there is potential harm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am trying to understand thought process behind this design decision

Only the person or people who actually made the decision can provide that. They are unlikely to see your question here, though of course that possibility can't be ruled out.

> is there any use case which makes current implementation a better choice?

There are lots of use cases. But the main thing to keep in mind is that adding the same object to a set (like `HashSet<T>`) that is already in the set is non-destructive, while adding the same key to a dictionary (like `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`) is destructive, i.e. it overwrites the existing value.

Having the `Add()` method return a `bool` like `HashSet<T>` does wouldn't be helpful; by the time you see the `false` value that's been returned, the old value for the key will have already been replaced.

That said, do note that the *indexer* for dictionaries *will* overwrite the existing value silently. So in fact, dictionaries have exactly the same functionality that `HashSet<T>`, *plus* the capability to prevent you from accidentally overwriting a value that's already been stored.